# How to directly open a folder by using an intent?

Tags: java, android

I want my application direct open file PDF in folder e-warta when click button open file.
But when I click my button always open like this

[image: image1]

I want to open like this
 [image: image2]

This is my button click
[image]

This is my code

```
openfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ File.separator+"e-warta"+File.separator);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Open"), PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Zoe thank's for your info. and sorry about that